# python3 string.find() gives inconsistent results

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on Greenhouse Monitor (like a weather station for my greenhouse). I'm using a Pi v3 wifi connected to house net with a bunch of sensors attached. The data is saved into an SQLite3 table and when queried sends the whole data base via sockets to my desktop. 
I am packaging my data into strings like this on the server side

```
elif dataReq == 'query':

    conn = sqlite3.connect(table_name)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute('SELECT * FROM ' + table_name)

    for row in curs.fetchall():
        timeStamp = row[0]
        Pressure = str(row[1])[0:6]
        Temperature = str(row[2])[0:5]
        Humidity = str(row[3])[0:5]
        Light = str(row[4])[0:6]
        Moisture = str(row[5])[0:3]
        dataPacket = '#' + timeStamp + ';' + Pressure + ';' + Temperature + ';' + Humidity + ';' + Light + ';' + Moisture + ';'
        BdataPacket = dataPacket.encode()
        C_sock.sendall(BdataPacket)
    curs.close()
    conn.close()
C_sock.close()
```

The "#" separates readings/db rows and ";" separates individual sensor readings.

Clientside I parse the data like this

```
    def parse_data(data):

        hsh = data.find("#", 0)
        while hsh != -1:
            Sta = hsh+1
            End = data.find(";", Sta)
            TimeStamp = data[Sta:End]

            Sta = data.find(";", hsh) + 1
            End = data.find(";", Sta)

            Pressure_str = data[Sta:End]

            Sta = data.find(";", End) + 1
            End = data.find(";", Sta)

            Temp_str = data[Sta:End]

            Sta = data.find(";", End) + 1
            End = data.find(";", Sta)

            Humidity_str = data[Sta:End]

            Sta = data.find(";", End) + 1
            End = data.find(";", Sta)

            Light_str = data[Sta:End]

            Sta = data.find(";", End) + 1
            End = data.find(";", Sta)

            Moisture_str = data[Sta:End]

            TimeStamp_L.append(TimeStamp)
            Pressure_L.append(float(Pressure_str))
            Temp_L.append(float(Temp_str))
            Humidity_L.append(float(Humidity_str))
            Light_L.append(float(Light_str))
            Moisture_L.append(float(Moisture_str))
            hsh = data.find("#", hsh + 1)
        return (Data_L)
```

The trouble is that when I hit the fetch button sometimes it works and sometimes it gives me errors suggesting that the parsing hasn't worked how it should.

here are some of the final lines from the error reports

ValueError: unconverted data remains: #2017-05-12 09:11:11.282566

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5#2017-05-11 20:23:02.949133'

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '98#2017-05-12 02:26:15.497014'

ValueError: time data '2017-05-11 17:48:31.#2017-05-11 17:35:59.425693' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

I cannot deduce any pattern in the errors, they happen first run, or fine for 5 then an error. Looks to me that .find() isn't working reliably - maybe someone knows better - or can fix this.

Comment: You didn't post enough code to tell for sure, but I'd guess the problem is in reassembling the received chunks into a stream.  Keep in mind that there is ABSOLUTELY NO CONNECTION between the size of the chunks that are received from a TCP socket, and the chunks that were sent - in the worst case, you might get only a single byte on each read.

Comment: The built-in string method `find()` works correctly. It is almost certain that the text you are working on is not the text you expected. That would cause unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for this, there seems little doubt to me that find() is not actually broken, it just looks like it and I was hoping for some insight into some aspect/behaviour I didn't know about. Code is sent with sendall followed by sock close which normally clears out the buffers. Don't overlook that the same data repeatedly sent sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. The algorithm might fail in finding the right end if truncated, but even if mangled at the start should at least begin with '#', which is not what I see in the error messages.

Comment: On reflection I think I will add a message terminator, from the server, and a count of the table rows so the client can work out if it has the whole thing, and if not keep trying. At least if this doesn't fix it I'll know it's not partial data.

Comment: In doing this I found the problem in some logic elsewhere. Sigh!